# Collapsing date records only if the value doesn't change - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need your help in solving the below problem in Oracle SQL.

Table 1(Input)

```
 Emp_ID Start_Date  End_Date    Rating  Department  Salary
2000    01012011    01012012    A   HR          10000
2000    01012012    01012013    A+  HR          20000
2000    01012013    12319999    A   HR          20000
3000    01012011    01012012    B   Operations  50000
3000    01012012    12319999    B   Operations  60000
```

Table 2(Output)

```
 Emp_ID Start_Date  End_Date    Rating  Department
2000    01012011    12312011    A   HR
2000    01012012    12312012    A+  HR
2000    01012013    12319999    A   HR
3000    01012011    12319999    B   Operations
```

Collapsing the date records only if the rating of the employee is same for the next continuous date range and it should continue until the rating changes..

I hope i made my question clear..

I looked at other answers and figured that i need to lead and lag functions.. But if some one could provide light on how to start that would be great..

Thanks

Comment: Any help guys..I am really struggling to solve this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a bit convoluted, so I'd be interested in improvements.

```
select distinct emp_id,
    nvl(x_start_date,
        lag(x_start_date)
            over (partition by emp_id
                order by rn)) as start_date,
    nvl(x_end_date,
        lead(x_end_date)
            over (partition by emp_id
                order by rn nulls first))
                    as end_date,
        rating,
        department
from (
    select emp_id, start_date, end_date, rating, department,
        case start_date
            when lag(end_date)
                over (partition by emp_id, rating, department
                    order by start_date) then null
            else start_date end as x_start_date,
        case end_date
            when lead(start_date)
                over (partition by emp_id, rating, department
                    order by start_date) then null
            else end_date end as x_end_date,
        rownum as rn
    from table1
)
where x_start_date is not null or x_end_date is not null
order by emp_id, start_date
/
```

With this test data:

```
    EMP_ID START_DA END_DATE RA DEPARTMENT               SALARY
---------- -------- -------- -- -------------------- ----------
      2000 01012010 01012011 A  HR                         9000
      2000 01012011 01012012 A  HR                        10000
      2000 01012012 01012013 A+ HR                        20000
      2000 01012013 01012014 A  HR                        20000
      2000 01012014 12319999 A  HR                        21000
      3000 01012011 01012012 B  Operations                50000
      3000 01012012 12319999 B  Operations                60000
      4000 07012011 07012012 B  Operations                50000
      4000 07012012 07012013 B  Operations                50000
      4000 07012013 12319999 B  Operations                60000
```

I get this:

```
    EMP_ID START_DA END_DATE RA DEPARTMENT
---------- -------- -------- -- --------------------
      2000 01012010 01012012 A  HR
      2000 01012012 01012013 A+ HR
      2000 01012013 12319999 A  HR
      3000 01012011 12319999 B  Operations
      4000 07012011 12319999 B  Operations
```

I also tried with an `emp_id` (`4000`) that had three contiguous date ranges, and it dealt with that OK - the outer `where` clause makes the intermediate entries disappear, essentially. **Edited to add**: Also now works with your additional date ranges for `2000/A`, since I fixed the ordering in the outer `lead`/`lag` partitions.

The inner query blanks out all but the first start date and last end date for a contiguous block, and the outer query uses a second round of `lead` and `lag` to merge them into identical rows, which the `distinct` then collapses.

I'm assuming `start_date` and `end_date` are `DATE` fields, not `VARCHAR2`, and you have `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` set to `MMDDYYYY`. If they are stored as strings, which is a bad idea, you need `to_date()` in quite a few places to make the ordering work properly.

Comment: Hi Alex, your code is almost working but i have tried the below cases  and it did not work. I added date 01012010 - 01012011 for emp_id 2000 of rating 'A' and 01012013 - 01012014 for emp_id 2000 of rating 'A'.. Is there way a you can add this..I know it is too much to ask :) Thanks

Comment: @javanoob: the ordering was messed up in the outer functions; I added the `rownum` psuedocolumn to the inner select and changed `lead`/`lag` to order by that, to preserve the work done in the inner select. I think the result is right now...

Comment: Thank you so much alex..but i am not getting the same result as u r getting..Is is the same query u used?.I am seeing few nulls in the output..I am really sorry for bothering you..

Comment: @javanoob - let's continue this in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13628)

Comment: Hi Alex, I think the problem is with the my input table, tried with the new input table and it is working flawless..Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from inputtable it1
left join inputtable it2 
       on it1.emp_id = it2.emp_id
      and it1.rating = it2.rating
      and it1.start_date < it2.start_date
      and not exists(select * from inputtable it2a
                     where it1.emp_id = it2a.emp_id
                       and ((it1.rating <> it2a.rating
                         and it1.start_date < it2a.start_date
                         and it2.start_date > it2a.start_date)
                         or (it1.rating = it2a.rating
                         and exists(select * from inputtable it2b
                                    where it2a.emp_id = it2b.emp_id
                                      and it2a.rating = it2b.rating
                                      and it2a.end_date + 1 = it2b.start_date))))
where not exists(select * from inputtable it1a
                 where it1.emp_id = it1a.emp_id
                   and it1.rating = it1a.rating
                   and it1.start_date = it1a.end_date + 1)
```

Comment: Almost there but not quite. The OP seems to want to display the collapsed range, not just the last subrange before the rating changes.

Comment: Right, I overlooked that the End_Date should come from another row (hence the additional left join). Answer modified.

Comment: Thank you for your time on solving this.its my bad I am not able to understand the logic..Thank you so much.