# Collapsing date ranges in SQL (Netezza)

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a data set that looks something like this:

```
Visit ID   Admission Date       Discharge Date       Unit
20         01/01/2015 12:45     01/01/2015 13:57     ER
20         01/03/2015 13:57     01/04/2015 11:57     ER
20         01/04/2015 11:57     01/04/2015 19:32     Trauma
20         01/04/2015 19:32     01/04/2015 21:22     ER
```

My goal is to get admission/discharge dates for each unit. The issue is that sometimes patients change beds within in the same unit, and this action is labeled as a transfer even though the patient is still within the same unit. So I would like to collapse those date ranges so the output instead looks like this:

```
Visit ID   Admission Date       Discharge Date       Unit
20         01/01/2015 12:45     01/01/2015 11:57     ER
20         01/04/2015 11:57     01/04/2015 19:32     Trauma
20         01/04/2015 19:32     01/04/2015 21:22     ER
```

I don't know how to achieve this...I was thinking of what partition I should use but every ranking partition I can think of (rank/dense_rank) will assign the first two ER values the same rank as the last ER value, which would be incorrect.

Basically, my question is the same this is unanswered question: [Collapsing date records only if the value doesn't change - Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355479/collapsing-date-records-only-if-the-value-doesnt-change-oracle-sql)

I'm using Netezza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `left join` to see if something is connected to the previous record.  If there is no connection, then you have the beginning of a "continuous period".  Then, a cumulative sum assigns a grouping, which can be used for aggregation.

That is how this query works:

```
select visitid, unit,
       min(admissiondate) as admissiondate,
       max(dischargedate) as dischargedate
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when tprev.visitid is null then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (partition by t.visitid, t.unit order by t.admissiondate 
                 ) as grp
      from t left join
           t tprev
           on t.visitid = tprev.visitid and t.unit = tprev.unit and
              t.admissiondate = tprev.dischargedate
     ) t
group by grp, visitid, unit;
```

Note:  This assumes that the new admission date is exactly the same as the previous discharge date.  Of course, you can introduce non-equality logic if you want to check that the admission occurred within, say 10 seconds or 5 minutes of the discharge.

Comment: Two questions:
1) Are the fields in the partition coming from t or tprev?
2) I'm not quite sure what the sum is doing, I can see the output but I'm admittedly confused

Comment: The fields are from `t`; `tprev` is only used to get the information for the flag.  The `sum()` is a cumulative sum which is used to assign a group to adjacent rows.  The value should be constant for what you want to call a group.